# How to retrieve a custom field translation with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, translation, visualstudiocode, package.xml, retrieve

I tried to retrieve the translation of a specific field but get: Nothing retrieved

This is what I tried:

```
sfdx project:retrieve:start -m "CustomFieldTranslation:Lead-nl_NL options__c" --target-org fullsb
```